# Error on running BSplines example in PCL 1.7

Tags: cloud, point, point-cloud-library

Why am I receiving the following error, when running the 'Fitting trimmed B-splines to unordered point clouds' example from the Point Cloud Library(PCL) tutorials, with the same CMakeLists file?

```
PCL : 1.7.1(compiled from source at /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7.1/pcl/)
OS : Ubuntu 12.04

CMakeFiles/bspline_fitting.dir/Bspline.cpp.o: In function `main': Bspline.cpp:(.text+0x282):`                                                             undefined reference to `PointCloud2Vector3d(boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`   >, std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>,   Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> > >&)'

Bspline.cpp:(.text+0xb41): undefined reference to `visualizeCurve(ON_NurbsCurve&, ON_NurbsSurface&, pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer&)'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [bspline_fitting] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bspline_fitting.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a temporary solution try to use the following code instead:

```
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>

#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/surface/on_nurbs/fitting_surface_tdm.h>
#include <pcl/surface/on_nurbs/fitting_curve_2d_asdm.h>
#include <pcl/surface/on_nurbs/triangulation.h>

typedef pcl::PointXYZ Point;

void
PointCloud2Vector3d (pcl::PointCloud<Point>::Ptr cloud, pcl::on_nurbs::vector_vec3d &data);

void
visualizeCurve (ON_NurbsCurve &curve,
                ON_NurbsSurface &surface,
                pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer &viewer);

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string pcd_file, file_3dm;

  if (argc < 3)
  {
    printf ("\nUsage: pcl_example_nurbs_fitting_surface pcd<PointXYZ>-in-file 3dm-out-file\n\n");
    exit (0);
  }
  pcd_file = argv[1];
  file_3dm = argv[2];

  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer ("B-spline surface fitting");
  viewer.setSize (800, 600);

  // ############################################################################
  // load point cloud

  printf ("  loading %s\n", pcd_file.c_str ());
  pcl::PointCloud<Point>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<Point>);
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud2;
  pcl::on_nurbs::NurbsDataSurface data;

  if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile (pcd_file, cloud2) == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error ("  PCD file not found.");

  fromPCLPointCloud2 (cloud2, *cloud);
  PointCloud2Vector3d (cloud, data.interior);
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<Point> handler (cloud, 0, 255, 0);
  viewer.addPointCloud<Point> (cloud, handler, "cloud_cylinder");
  printf ("  %zu points in data set\n", cloud->size ());

  // ############################################################################
  // fit B-spline surface

  // parameters
  unsigned order (3);
  unsigned refinement (5);
  unsigned iterations (10);
  unsigned mesh_resolution (256);

  pcl::on_nurbs::FittingSurface::Parameter params;
  params.interior_smoothness = 0.2;
  params.interior_weight = 1.0;
  params.boundary_smoothness = 0.2;
  params.boundary_weight = 0.0;

  // initialize
  printf ("  surface fitting ...\n");
  ON_NurbsSurface nurbs = pcl::on_nurbs::FittingSurface::initNurbsPCABoundingBox (order, &data);
  pcl::on_nurbs::FittingSurface fit (&data, nurbs);
  //  fit.setQuiet (false); // enable/disable debug output

  // mesh for visualization
  pcl::PolygonMesh mesh;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr mesh_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  std::vector<pcl::Vertices> mesh_vertices;
  std::string mesh_id = "mesh_nurbs";
  pcl::on_nurbs::Triangulation::convertSurface2PolygonMesh (fit.m_nurbs, mesh, mesh_resolution);
  viewer.addPolygonMesh (mesh, mesh_id);

  // surface refinement
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < refinement; i++)
  {
    fit.refine (0);
    fit.refine (1);
    fit.assemble (params);
    fit.solve ();
    pcl::on_nurbs::Triangulation::convertSurface2Vertices (fit.m_nurbs, mesh_cloud, mesh_vertices, mesh_resolution);
    viewer.updatePolygonMesh<pcl::PointXYZ> (mesh_cloud, mesh_vertices, mesh_id);
    viewer.spinOnce ();
  }

  // surface fitting with final refinement level
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
  {
    fit.assemble (params);
    fit.solve ();
    pcl::on_nurbs::Triangulation::convertSurface2Vertices (fit.m_nurbs, mesh_cloud, mesh_vertices, mesh_resolution);
    viewer.updatePolygonMesh<pcl::PointXYZ> (mesh_cloud, mesh_vertices, mesh_id);
    viewer.spinOnce ();
  }

  // ############################################################################
  // fit B-spline curve

  // parameters
  pcl::on_nurbs::FittingCurve2dAPDM::FitParameter curve_params;
  curve_params.addCPsAccuracy = 5e-2;
  curve_params.addCPsIteration = 3;
  curve_params.maxCPs = 200;
  curve_params.accuracy = 1e-3;
  curve_params.iterations = 100;

  curve_params.param.closest_point_resolution = 0;
  curve_params.param.closest_point_weight = 1.0;
  curve_params.param.closest_point_sigma2 = 0.1;
  curve_params.param.interior_sigma2 = 0.00001;
  curve_params.param.smooth_concavity = 1.0;
  curve_params.param.smoothness = 1.0;

  // initialisation (circular)
  printf ("  curve fitting ...\n");
  pcl::on_nurbs::NurbsDataCurve2d curve_data;
  curve_data.interior = data.interior_param;
  curve_data.interior_weight_function.push_back (true);
  ON_NurbsCurve curve_nurbs = pcl::on_nurbs::FittingCurve2dAPDM::initNurbsCurve2D (order, curve_data.interior);

  // curve fitting
  pcl::on_nurbs::FittingCurve2dASDM curve_fit (&curve_data, curve_nurbs);
  // curve_fit.setQuiet (false); // enable/disable debug output
  curve_fit.fitting (curve_params);
  visualizeCurve (curve_fit.m_nurbs, fit.m_nurbs, viewer);

  // ############################################################################
  // triangulation of trimmed surface

  printf ("  triangulate trimmed surface ...\n");
  viewer.removePolygonMesh (mesh_id);
  pcl::on_nurbs::Triangulation::convertTrimmedSurface2PolygonMesh (fit.m_nurbs, curve_fit.m_nurbs, mesh,
                                                                   mesh_resolution);
  viewer.addPolygonMesh (mesh, mesh_id);


  // save trimmed B-spline surface
  //if ( fit.m_nurbs.IsValid() )
  //{
  //  ONX_Model model;
  //  ONX_Model_Object& surf = model.m_object_table.AppendNew();
  //  surf.m_object = new ON_NurbsSurface(fit.m_nurbs);
  //  surf.m_bDeleteObject = true;
  //  surf.m_attributes.m_layer_index = 1;
  //  surf.m_attributes.m_name = "surface";

  //  ONX_Model_Object& curv = model.m_object_table.AppendNew();
  //  curv.m_object = new ON_NurbsCurve(curve_fit.m_nurbs);
  //  curv.m_bDeleteObject = true;
  //  curv.m_attributes.m_layer_index = 2;
  //  curv.m_attributes.m_name = "trimming curve";

  //  model.Write(file_3dm.c_str());
  //  printf("  model saved: %s\n", file_3dm.c_str());
  //}

  printf ("  ... done.\n");

  viewer.spin ();
  return 0;
}

void
PointCloud2Vector3d (pcl::PointCloud<Point>::Ptr cloud, pcl::on_nurbs::vector_vec3d &data)
{
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < cloud->size (); i++)
  {
    Point &p = cloud->at (i);
    if (!pcl_isnan (p.x) && !pcl_isnan (p.y) && !pcl_isnan (p.z))
      data.push_back (Eigen::Vector3d (p.x, p.y, p.z));
  }
}

void
visualizeCurve (ON_NurbsCurve &curve, ON_NurbsSurface &surface, pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer &viewer)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr curve_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

  pcl::on_nurbs::Triangulation::convertCurve2PointCloud (curve, surface, curve_cloud, 4);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < curve_cloud->size () - 1; i++)
  {
    pcl::PointXYZRGB &p1 = curve_cloud->at (i);
    pcl::PointXYZRGB &p2 = curve_cloud->at (i + 1);
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "line" << i;
    viewer.removeShape (os.str ());
    viewer.addLine<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (p1, p2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, os.str ());
  }

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr curve_cps (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  for (int i = 0; i < curve.CVCount (); i++)
  {
    ON_3dPoint p1;
    curve.GetCV (i, p1);

    double pnt[3];
    surface.Evaluate (p1.x, p1.y, 0, 3, pnt);
    pcl::PointXYZRGB p2;
    p2.x = float (pnt[0]);
    p2.y = float (pnt[1]);
    p2.z = float (pnt[2]);

    p2.r = 255;
    p2.g = 0;
    p2.b = 0;

    curve_cps->push_back (p2);
  }
  viewer.removePointCloud ("cloud_cps");
  viewer.addPointCloud (curve_cps, "cloud_cps");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i am getting the exact same error.

bspline_fitting.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl visualizeCurve(class ON_NurbsCurve &,class ON_NurbsSurface &,class pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer &)" (?visualizeCurve@@YAXAAVON_NurbsCurve@@AAVON_NurbsSurface@@AAVPCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@@Z) referenced in function _main

2>bspline_fitting.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl PointCloud2Vector3d(class boost::shared_ptr >,class std::vector,class Eigen::aligned_allocator > > &)" (?PointCloud2Vector3d@@YAXV?$shared_ptr@V?$PointCloud@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@@boost@@AAV?$vector@V?$Matrix@N$02$00$0A@$02$00@Eigen@@V?$aligned_allocator@V?$Matrix@N$02$00$0A@$02$00@Eigen@@@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main

im running it on windows 7 in MS visual studio 10